# Inserting GUID into SQL Server

Tags: sql, insert, guid

I have a stored proc were I want to insert a GUID (user id) into a table in MS SQL but I keep getting an error about the hyphen '-' that is part of the guid value, here's my proc defined below;

```
@userID uniqueidentifier,
@bookID int,
@dateReserved datetime,
@status bit

INSERT INTO Reservation(BookId, DateReserved, [Status], UserId)
VALUES (@bookID, @dateReserved, @status, @userID)
```

But when I put single quotes around the value if the stored proc is executed in Management Studio, it runs fine. How can I handle the guid insertion without problems from my stored proc?

Thanks guys.

**Update**
Here's the sql exec

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_ReserveBook]
    @userID = AE019609-99E0-4EF5-85BB-AD90DC302E70,
    @bookID = 7,
    @dateReserved = N'09/03/2009',
    @status = 1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Here's the error message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

Comment: Did you transpose your userid and bookid arguments by mistake?  Can you post an example EXEC statement that is causing the bug.  Your SQL so far looks fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just cast it from a varchar.

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_ReserveBook]
        @userID = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, 'AE019609-99E0-4EF5-85BB-AD90DC302E70'),
        @bookID = 7,
        @dateReserved = N'09/03/2009',
        @status = 1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Answer (score 10):

You simply need to **QUOTE** your GUID:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_ReserveBook]
        @userID = 'AE019609-99E0-4EF5-85BB-AD90DC302E70',  
        @bookID = 7,
        @dateReserved = N'09/03/2009',
        @status = 1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Marc

Comment: beat me by 4 seconds. Removing mine.

Comment: Yea I noticed that, so how can i do that from my stored proc, because when I tried doing that, an error saying a varchar can't be converted to a uniqueidentifier was what i got. Thanks

Comment: @simply: sounds like that* is the real problem; can you add that line of code which creates that varchar/uid error message?

Comment: Using a string only works in some cases. Converting the string to uniquidentifier works in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need single quotes around your GUID....it's just a string to sql server.

You could try letting the sp generate the GUID with the sql function newid()  ...sql server only i think.

And if you're pulling the GUID from another table, let the SP go get that GUID from that table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
sql_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue
("@Company_ID",**Guid.Parse**("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
```

That will take a simple string rep. and turn it into a GUID obj.