# How to use Iqueryable object in ExceuteCommand ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table with following definition.

```
Create table RecipientInGroups
{
  ID uniqueidentifier,
  GroupID uniqueidentifier,
  RID uniqueidentifier,
  CreateDt datetime
}
```

I am trying to run below code:

```
var strCommandText = dc.GetCommand(finalRecp).CommandText;

strCommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO RecipientInGroups SELECT '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}'", Guid.NewGuid(), gGroupId, finalRecp, now);

dc.ExecuteQuery<EmailRecipientInGroup>(strCommandText);
```

where finalRecp is queryable object created based on certain conditions.

But I am getting below error for finalRecp:

> ERROR 2015-02-08 00:04:39,070 - [CopyContcatsToGroup] -
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): **Conversion failed
>   when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.**    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object
>   instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(String command, Object[]
>   parameters)

How can I use finalRecp(IQueryable) object to insert values in ExecuteQuery or ExecuteCommand? Also how I can create new ID for every RID that I insert using ExecuteQuery or ExecuteCommand?

Assuming that my question is confusing lot people, the final query that is generated is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO RecipientInGroups SELECT '404f8892-8a1a-4d65-abc1-174c41ce89f7', '662f4f05-0d9f-4036-b048-74178413f033', 'SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[RID]
FROM [dbo].[EmailRecipients] AS [t0]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [t11].[RID]
        FROM (
            SELECT [t10].[RID]
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT [t4].[RID]
                FROM [dbo].[UserGroupMessageEmailDetail] AS [t1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserGroupMessages] AS [t2] ON [t2].[ID] = [t1].[GroupMessageID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_Users] AS [t3] ON [t3].[UserId] = [t2].[UserId]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserEmailRecipients] AS [t4] ON [t4].[RID] = [t1].[RID]
                WHERE ([t1].[GroupMessageID] = @p0) AND ([t3].[LoweredUserName] = LOWER(@p1))
                UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT [t9].[RID]
                FROM [dbo].[UserGroupMessageContactDetails] AS [t5]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserGroupMessages] AS [t6] ON [t6].[ID] = [t5].[GroupMessageID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_Users] AS [t7] ON [t7].[UserId] = [t6].[UserId]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserContacts] AS [t8] ON [t8].[ContactID] = [t5].[ContactID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserEmailRecipients] AS [t9] ON [t9].[RID] = [t8].[ContactID]
                WHERE ([t7].[LoweredUserName] = @p2) AND ([t5].[GroupMessageID] = @p3) AND (NOT ([t9].[IsDeleted] = 1))
                ) AS [t10]
            ) AS [t11]
        ) AS [t12]
    WHERE [t12].[RID] = [t0].[RID]
    )
', '02-09-2015 06:14:15 AM'
```

and i am thinking the issue is coming in 3rd parameter insertion.

Please let me know if any more information is needed...

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959826/inserting-guid-into-sql-server

Comment: Your implementation, and the accepted answer on the question I've marked it a duplicate of, are both terrible, horribly, completely wide open to a SQL injection attack. I hesitated to mark it a dupe as a result, but there's this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1436001/21418 which correctly tells you to parameterize your query.

Comment: @Euphoric, Gert Arnold... Please read my question carefully. The links that you suggested was trying to insert single HARDCODED GUID (even though from c# Guid.NewGuid()). I am trying to insert mutilple records from IQUERYABLE object(finalrecp).. Basically I am trying to impletement equivalent of (INSERT... SELECT... FROM) in SQL from LINQ2SQL or EntityFramework. Please remove Duplicate mark from these questions. If needed I can put the code for finalRecp as well....

Comment: Please, read your question carefully. You are inserting Guid.NewGuid(). Also, your code doesn't make sense because whenever is in strCommandText when it gets initialized from command text gets immediately overwritten on next line.  Learn how variables and references really work.

Comment: @Euphoric, what is the problem with using "Guid.NewGuid()"?. Also what is it that not making sense in overwriting strCommandText? If I don't want to create two variable, why can't I use same variable and reuse it?

Comment: @Euphoric please see the final query that i am trying to execute... I am thinking that while inserting 3rd variable it is throwing exception... Please help...